Evaluate $\int_0^4 \int_{x^{1/2}}^2\frac1{4+y^3}dydx$
Please help me to evaluate the following double integral:
$$\int_0^4 \int_{x^{1/2}}^2\frac1{4+y^3}dydx.$$
I can't seem to get an answer that makes sense but online calculators can find a solution so I know one exists.
I tried swapping the bounds of integration already and the answer also seemed to be odd. I got $(1/24)\ln(68) - (1/0  )\ln(16)  - \ln (\sqrt[3]{17})$ and needed to do $u$ sub with nothing to divide out the $1/(3y^2)$. I approached that like an additional variable and treated it as a constant but I'm pretty sure you cant do that. The $\ln (\sqrt[3]{17})$ was done properly though (I think).
Photo of work

It seems that you may change the order of integration, then everything will be simplified.

Please include in your post how you found your (erroneous) result. This will help us to pinpoint your mistake.

By changing the order of integration, we obtain that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{0}^{4}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{2}\frac{1}{4+y^{3}}dydx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}\frac{1}{4+y^{3}}dxdy\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{2}\frac{y^{2}}{4+y^{3}}dy\\
 & = & \frac{1}{3}\ln\left(4+y^{3}\right)\vert_{0}^{2}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{3}\ln3.
\end{eqnarray*}

Imo more pedagogical than spoonfeeding you with a readymade solution.
Please don’t use images instead of typing your formulas.
Your attempt contains at least 4 mistakes:

The upper bound for $y$ should remain $2$, not become $4$, which was the upper bound for $x$.
$x$ should vary from $0$ to $y^2$, not from $y^2$ to $2$.
$\int\frac2u\frac1{3y^2}du=\int\frac2u\frac1{3(u-4)^{2/3}}du\ne\frac2{3y^2}
\int\frac1udu$
$\frac2{3y^2}[\ln(4+y^3)]_0^4=\frac2{3y^2}\ln(17)\ne\left[\frac2{3y^2}\ln(4+y^3)\right]_0^4$.

